Add exception handler and continue code execution
I have this Python code used to read files:
import pandas as pd

metadata_files = []
csv_df = pd.DataFrame()
meta_files_list = (pd.read_csv(file, encoding='utf-8', sep=";") for file in metadata_files)
meta_files_df = pd.concat(meta_files_list, ignore_index=True)

Sometimes I get an exception because files are empty at the line pd.concat.
How I can properly process this exception and continue program execution?
I want to send a message somehow to process this issue.

You could use try and except syntax of python:
metadata_files = []
csv_df = pd.DataFrame()
meta_files_list = (pd.read_csv(file, encoding='utf-8', sep=";") for file in 
metadata_files)
try:
  meta_files_df = pd.concat(meta_files_list, ignore_index=True)
except:
  print("could not concat")

Simply add what you want to do in the case of concat not working.
